# UserControl vs SurfaceWindow

Tags: wpf, windows, user-controls, dependencies

I am trying to use values i declare inside a UserControl class to change things inside the SurfaceWindow class. Now what i know so far is that i have to use a DependencyProperty to get the value from the UserControl and then put it inside a public string.

```
  public string MapValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MapValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly
        DependencyProperty MapValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MapValue", typeof(string), typeof(MapManager));
```

Now my question is, how do i bind the public string (that is inside the UserControl) to a element (inside the SurfaceWindow)?

If i use the DependencyProperty do i make a new class or do i put it in the usercontrol code?

I would be very happy if someone could help me with this problem..

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell you are trying to bind to a dependency property of some control in your window.

If this is the case you could use the ElementName syntax in the binding declarations such as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MapControl, Path=MapValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had already have this inside my window control:

`<Image x:Name="iGroundPlan" Source="{Binding ElementName=MapManager,Path=MapValue}" />`

(MapManager is the name of my usercontrol)

But looks like it aint working, and i dont know why.. Its like the windows never knows when the value MapValue is updated in my usercontrol =\

Comment: 1. How do you update the Mapvalue? Give us an example. (could be a Mode=Twoway issue) 
2. Is it a valid Image? Try using a textblock just to see what the actual value is, and whether it gets updated or not.